# Multiple v-for loops with different keys still causing duplicate key error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a python application that is using Vue.js, and a ticket was thrown back at me with an error of:

> [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: ''. This may cause an update error. (found 
>   in Root)

Problem is none of the keys in any of the `v-for:` loops are the same.

They all look like this:

`<li class="page-item" v-for="p in pagesArray" :key="p.label+'label'">...`

`<b-form-checkbox v-for="(skill, index) in visibleSkills" :key="skill.skillname+'-name'">...`

`<b-form-radio v-for="(bundle, index) in visibleBundles" :key="bundle.bundlename">...`

Any insight on this from anywhere, because the stack trace is not helpful, and I've parsed all the docs already.

Comment: seems like your bundle.bundlename has multiple empty string records.
have you tried console log visibleBundles?

Comment: that might be it let me try that out.

Comment: did you try also to concatenate the `index` in order to enforce the uniqueness?

Comment: it is the bundle name you were correct and I am going to try to concate the index now. Did you want to submit it as an answer, and i'll get you some love for it! Thanks mate

Comment: yup it is fixed thank you all for the help

Comment: Make sure the bundle.bundlename key is not empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate the index in order to enforce the uniqueness :

```
  <li class="page-item" v-for="(p,index) in pagesArray" :key="p.label+'label'+index">
  <b-form-checkbox v-for="(skill, index) in visibleSkills" :key="skill.skillname+'-name'+index">
  <b-form-radio v-for="(bundle, index) in visibleBundles" :key="bundle.bundlename+index">
```